# How to make more than one page with OpenTbs?

Tags: php, opentbs

I want to make a report receipt, if more than one then the data will be displayed on the next page, the following code that I have made :

```
[dataJmn;block=begin]
[onshow.~tablename.DetilProduct;noerr]
[dataJmn;block=end]
```

Thanks

Edited :

So, the above code I fixed it to be like this, but another obstacle emerged, namely the use of the function IF ELSE in DOCX is like what ?

```
1 (One) Unit Vehicle : 
Brand : [dataJmn.VehicleBrand;noerr], Type : [dataJmn.VehicleType;noerr], Machine : [dataJmn.VehicleMachine;noerr]


1 (One) Unit Estate : 
House Type : [dataJmn.HouseType;noerr], Address : [dataJmn.HouseAddress;noerr]
```

I have two data [vehicle & estate], when the vehicle data in a data view vehicle only, so also on the contrary

Comment: I believe you can simply edit the first row of your table in Word to include a page break before: http://www.tinybutstrong.com/forum.php?thr=3354

Comment: I guess your template is a DOCX. Can you explain why you are using a block "dataJmn" but the only thing which is displayed inside is single value apparently not linked to block.